# How to indent text while preserving vertical alignment?

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to implement a layout similar to the following image:

[image]

I have a box with two text elements (say two `<span>`s) in it, the one of the left has a slightly smaller font size than the one on the right. Normally, in cases like this, if you want to center-align two text elements with different font sizes, you'd use `vertical-align: middle` on both. This works, of course, but it only works if the elements are both inline, and if they're inline, then when the text on the right is wrapped (i.e. broken into multiple lines), all the other lines start from the beginning, like this:

[image]

But this isn't what I want, **I want the second piece of text (the one on the right) to start where the left text ends for all the lines**. Just like in the first image above.

Now, obviously the first impulse is to implement this using flexbox, but the problem with that approach is that using `vertical-align: middle` on the two text elements would no longer work and you'd have no way of center-aligning the smaller text on the left with the first line of the text on the right vertically.

Example:

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEEEF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.note {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.right {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<p class="note">
  Notice how the text "Section 1." is not vertically aligned with the first line of the text on the right:
</p>

<div class="box">
  <span class="left">Section 1.</span>
  <span class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?</span>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Try giving your box class a line-height so each span shares the same baseline, though they're different font sizes.

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEEEF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 27px;
}

.left {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.right {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span class="left">Section 1.</span>
  <span class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `align-items: baseline;` to `.box`

> ```
> .box {
>    background-color: white;
>    border-radius: 10px;
>    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
>    padding: 20px 30px;
>    display: flex;
>    align-items: baseline;
>  }
> ```

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEEEF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.note {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  margin: .25rem;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.left {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.right {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<p class="note">
  Notice how the text "Section 1." is now vertically aligned with the first line of the text on the right:
</p>

<div class="box">
  <span class="left">Section 1.</span>
  <span class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This puts "Section 1." on top of the rest of the text, which isn't the layout I want. Please take a look at the first image in the original question, which illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Look at the correction I just made.

Comment: The use of `align-items: baseline` is clever, thanks, but it still doesn't actually center the left side text with the first line of the right one, it aligns the left side text with the **bottom** of the first line of the right one.

Comment: Then it looks like Maggie Cody got it right

Answer (score 1):

Use a pseudo element having the same font-size as the big text to recreate the initial situation and you can use `vertical-align`

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEEEF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.note {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.left:before {
  content: "";
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.right,
.left:before {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<p class="note">
  Notice how the text "Section 1." is not vertically aligned with the first line of the text on the right:
</p>

<div class="box">
  <span class="left">Section 1.</span>
  <span class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Grids to achieve this functionality. If you don't know about CSS Grids, it is a very helpful utility in CSS and it will be used in almost every webpage. I highly suggest you to learn CSS Grids from [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp).
See how it works:

```
.box{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
}
```

That's it, see the changes and you'll be amazed and now you can do further changes to alignment.
Meanwhile, (if you don't have much time to learn CSS Grids) you can continue with creating a table and the adding the two span elements in a single row, but different cells.

Comment: The owner of the post is using flex as the layout. The problem here is that the left and right texts are different sizes. That's why it doesn't align horizontally.

Comment: I don't think using CSS grid solves my problem in this case, can you please provide a runnable code snippet?

Comment: Hey, my method still works, but actually I didn't read the last line of question where you asked about the vertical alignment. Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vp5jbg6s/ . I just changed the CSS Properties of `.left` and `.box`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEEEF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.note {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: start;
}

.left {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  min-width: fit-content;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.right {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<p class="note">
  Notice how the text "Section 1." is not vertically aligned with the first line of the text on the right:
</p>

<div class="box">
  <span class="left">Section 1.</span>
  <span class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not actually a proper solution, you're merely hard-coding a `padding-top` of `2px` for the `.left` element.